# Dual booting problem

Tags: dual-boot

After dual booting ubuntu17.04 with windows 8.1 ,I can't access windows . There is an option of windows 8 on GNU GRUB , after clicking on windows option the pointer comes back. windows 8 is not opening....please find the error and give me the solution

Comment: Grub can only boot working Windows. If it wasn't booting before you made it worse now, but try `sudo update-grub` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be giving the boot option on BIOS a shot.
When you enter bios (You might as well just tap Esc repeatedly after starting your machine until you see a boot menu) Once on there, select the windows boot option.